# Start async "context" from non async method - non blocking wait using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I’d like to use async/await pattern in a non async context inside of a C# Windows Service.
I’ve to work with a non async Queue API.
The definition of the communicator class of the API (used for the communication) contains an event which gets fired whenever someone send a message to my application over the queue.
In my event handler, I need to start a new thread or use the ThreadPool to process the received message on a different thread, so that the application can still receive other messages in the meantime.

Usually I would do this like so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( x => { /* message processing here */ } );
```

But in this case I would like to use the async/await pattern in the message processing.
Do I need to start a new Task and await it using the Task’s Wait method or is there a better way to do this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( x => Task
    .Run( async () =>
    {
      // await async operation here
    } )
    .Wait() );
```

I still use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in the second item because the message processing should not block, so that the application can still receive other message during processing.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Typically, I/O is done asynchronously, and mostly the built-in I/O classes use the IOCP thread pool to handle I/O completions. Thus, you are already in a separate thread when e.g. a message is received. I would say you certainly _should not_ queue a work item to the thread pool just for the purpose of calling `Task.Run()`. That's silly. The `Task.Run()` method will, in most contexts, by default queue the task to the thread pool anyway. Further more, calling `Task.Run()` to execute code just to then use `await` is similarly silly.

Comment: If you have code that you actually need help with, distill it into a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, and describe in precise detail what _specifically_ you are having trouble with, what the code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your comment. 1) The queue library does publish the event on the same thread as the library uses to fetch new messages. 2) For processing the message I would like to reuse some of the existing BLL classes which are all written using async/await. I can rewrite the BLL, change the “old” code already using the BLL classes or I can do a “hack” in this Service so that I can use the async methods of the BLL classes. About the example, I can add my BLL code to the question but I cannot see how this would help to understand the problem.